# Nothing-At-Stacke: What is EV and why can I not vote on both branches with full stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

Can somebody tell me what EV means and what the graphs represent?

Does p=0.9 means that I look 0.9 of my stake for the one branch and 0.1 for the other? Where does this locking happens? Why can't I vote for both branches with my "whole steak"? (if this steak thing is correct).

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ#what-is-the-nothing-at-stake-problem-and-how-can-it-be-fixed

Answer (score 1):

EV means expected value. It is the average you will receive if you repeat the experiment a large number of times.

p=0.9 means if you choose that branch you have 90% probability of it being the correct one.

The locking happens when you "vote".

You can vote both alternatives. They analyze that case and propose possible solutions to prevent that behavior.

Comment: But why is the probability not 0.5 for both branches?
If everyone is following the same procedure on mining on both?

Comment: It is just an example. Everybody should have about the same probability to generate a new block. Once it was generated how it propagates depends on external factors like network connectivity between nodes.